# pandas: keyword error while accessing column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which at beginning looks like this
[image]

Now I did some computation with the dataframe and the code is as follows

```
df_sorted = (df.groupby(df['location_id'])['users'].nunique()).to_frame()
df_sorted = df_sorted.sort_values(['users'], ascending=False)
```

now the dataframe looks like this
[image]

but now I cannot access location_id from new dataframe with following code

```
df_sorted['location_id']
```

I get error saying `KeyError: 'location_id'`
However when i do

```
df_sorted['users]
```

I get entire dataframe like[image]

Any idea why??

Comment: `location_id` becomes `index` after `groupby()`

Comment: You should stop at `groupby()` and see what your dataframe was after that step :D

Comment: As @zipa says, `location_id` is now an index, so you either access the index by `df_sorted.index` or you make a new column `df.sorted['location_id'] = df_sorted.index`

Comment: When in doubt inspect `df.columns`, or better yet `df.columns.tolist()` to spot blank spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location_id` becomes `index` after `groupby()`.
What you can do is use:

```
df_sorted = df_sorted.sort_values(['users'], ascending=False).reset_index()
```

This will return to previous indexing and turn `location_id` into column.